# find the number all $a$ less than 1000 such that the number of different prime divisors of them is $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Let $a$ be a natural number such that the number of different prime divisors of $a$ is $2$. For example $6=2\times 3$, or $12=2^2\times 3$ or $225=3^2\times 5^2$.

Now find the number all $a$ less than 1000?

My attempt: we  must use of the prime numbers
$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31$

Comment: Not pleasant. You will need a list of the primes less than $500$, and a systematic process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate $p$ downward starting from the highest prime below $500$. Iterate $k$ from $1$ to $\log_p(500)$. Iterate $q$ from $2$ up through primes less than $\frac{1000}{p^k}$. Iterate $j$ from $1$ to $\log_q(1000/p^k)$.

This captures all $p^kq^j$ that are less than $1000$.

Comment: This is an effective approach.  It would work well if the limit were much higher than $1000$ as long as you have a list of primes up to the square root of the limit, which is not hard with a sieve.

Answer (score 0):

- $6 = 2 \times 3$
- $10 = 2 \times 5$
- $12 = 2^2 \times 3$
- $14 = 2 \times 7$
- $15 = 3 \times 5$
- $18 = 2 \times 3^2$
- $20 = 2^2 \times 5$
- $21 = 3 \times 7$
- $22 = 2 \times 11$
- $24 = 2^3 \times 3$
- $26 = 2 \times 13$
- $28 = 2^2 \times 7$
- $33 = 3 \times 11$
- $34 = 2 \times 17$
- $35 = 5 \times 7$
- $36 = 2^2 \times 3^2$
- $38 = 2 \times 19$
- $39 = 3 \times 13$
- $40 = 2^3 \times 5$
- $44 = 2^2 \times 11$
- $45 = 3^2 \times 5$
- $46 = 2 \times 23$
- $48 = 2^4 \times 3$
- $50 = 2 \times 5^2$
- $51 = 3 \times 17$
- $52 = 2^2 \times 13$
- $54 = 2 \times 3^3$
- $55 = 5 \times 11$
- $56 = 2^3 \times 7$
- $57 = 3 \times 19$
- $58 = 2 \times 29$
- $62 = 2 \times 31$
- $63 = 3^2 \times 7$
- $65 = 5 \times 13$
- $68 = 2^2 \times 17$
- $69 = 3 \times 23$
- $72 = 2^3 \times 3^2$
- $74 = 2 \times 37$
- $75 = 3 \times 5^2$
- $76 = 2^2 \times 19$
- $77 = 7 \times 11$
- $80 = 2^4 \times 5$
- $82 = 2 \times 41$
- $85 = 5 \times 17$
- $86 = 2 \times 43$
- $87 = 3 \times 29$
- $88 = 2^3 \times 11$
- $91 = 7 \times 13$
- $92 = 2^2 \times 23$
- $93 = 3 \times 31$
- $94 = 2 \times 47$
- $95 = 5 \times 19$
- $96 = 2^5 \times 3$
- $98 = 2 \times 7^2$
- $99 = 3^2 \times 11$
- $100 = 2^2 \times 5^2$
- $104 = 2^3 \times 13$
- $106 = 2 \times 53$
- $108 = 2^2 \times 3^3$
- $111 = 3 \times 37$
- $112 = 2^4 \times 7$
- $115 = 5 \times 23$
- $116 = 2^2 \times 29$
- $117 = 3^2 \times 13$
- $118 = 2 \times 59$
- $119 = 7 \times 17$
- $122 = 2 \times 61$
- $123 = 3 \times 41$
- $124 = 2^2 \times 31$
- $129 = 3 \times 43$
- $133 = 7 \times 19$
- $134 = 2 \times 67$
- $135 = 3^3 \times 5$
- $136 = 2^3 \times 17$
- $141 = 3 \times 47$
- $142 = 2 \times 71$
- $143 = 11 \times 13$
- $144 = 2^4 \times 3^2$
- $145 = 5 \times 29$
- $146 = 2 \times 73$
- $147 = 3 \times 7^2$
- $148 = 2^2 \times 37$
- $152 = 2^3 \times 19$
- $153 = 3^2 \times 17$
- $155 = 5 \times 31$
- $158 = 2 \times 79$
- $159 = 3 \times 53$
- $160 = 2^5 \times 5$
- $161 = 7 \times 23$
- $162 = 2 \times 3^4$
- $164 = 2^2 \times 41$
- $166 = 2 \times 83$
- $171 = 3^2 \times 19$
- $172 = 2^2 \times 43$
- $175 = 5^2 \times 7$
- $176 = 2^4 \times 11$
- $177 = 3 \times 59$
- $178 = 2 \times 89$
- $183 = 3 \times 61$
- $184 = 2^3 \times 23$
- $185 = 5 \times 37$
- $187 = 11 \times 17$
- $188 = 2^2 \times 47$
- $189 = 3^3 \times 7$
- $192 = 2^6 \times 3$
- $194 = 2 \times 97$
- $196 = 2^2 \times 7^2$
- $200 = 2^3 \times 5^2$
- $201 = 3 \times 67$
- $202 = 2 \times 101$
- $203 = 7 \times 29$
- $205 = 5 \times 41$
- $206 = 2 \times 103$
- $207 = 3^2 \times 23$
- $208 = 2^4 \times 13$
- $209 = 11 \times 19$
- $212 = 2^2 \times 53$
- $213 = 3 \times 71$
- $214 = 2 \times 107$
- $215 = 5 \times 43$
- $216 = 2^3 \times 3^3$
- $217 = 7 \times 31$
- $218 = 2 \times 109$
- $219 = 3 \times 73$
- $221 = 13 \times 17$
- $224 = 2^5 \times 7$
- $225 = 3^2 \times 5^2$
- $226 = 2 \times 113$
- $232 = 2^3 \times 29$
- $235 = 5 \times 47$
- $236 = 2^2 \times 59$
- $237 = 3 \times 79$
- $242 = 2 \times 11^2$
- $244 = 2^2 \times 61$
- $245 = 5 \times 7^2$
- $247 = 13 \times 19$
- $248 = 2^3 \times 31$
- $249 = 3 \times 83$
- $250 = 2 \times 5^3$
- $253 = 11 \times 23$
- $254 = 2 \times 127$
- $259 = 7 \times 37$
- $261 = 3^2 \times 29$
- $262 = 2 \times 131$
- $265 = 5 \times 53$
- $267 = 3 \times 89$
- $268 = 2^2 \times 67$
- $272 = 2^4 \times 17$
- $274 = 2 \times 137$
- $275 = 5^2 \times 11$
- $278 = 2 \times 139$
- $279 = 3^2 \times 31$
- $284 = 2^2 \times 71$
- $287 = 7 \times 41$
- $288 = 2^5 \times 3^2$
- $291 = 3 \times 97$
- $292 = 2^2 \times 73$
- $295 = 5 \times 59$
- $296 = 2^3 \times 37$
- $297 = 3^3 \times 11$
- $298 = 2 \times 149$
- $299 = 13 \times 23$
- $301 = 7 \times 43$
- $302 = 2 \times 151$
- $303 = 3 \times 101$
- $304 = 2^4 \times 19$
- $305 = 5 \times 61$
- $309 = 3 \times 103$
- $314 = 2 \times 157$
- $316 = 2^2 \times 79$
- $319 = 11 \times 29$
- $320 = 2^6 \times 5$
- $321 = 3 \times 107$
- $323 = 17 \times 19$
- $324 = 2^2 \times 3^4$
- $325 = 5^2 \times 13$
- $326 = 2 \times 163$
- $327 = 3 \times 109$
- $328 = 2^3 \times 41$
- $329 = 7 \times 47$
- $332 = 2^2 \times 83$
- $333 = 3^2 \times 37$
- $334 = 2 \times 167$
- $335 = 5 \times 67$
- $338 = 2 \times 13^2$
- $339 = 3 \times 113$
- $341 = 11 \times 31$
- $344 = 2^3 \times 43$
- $346 = 2 \times 173$
- $351 = 3^3 \times 13$
- $352 = 2^5 \times 11$
- $355 = 5 \times 71$
- $356 = 2^2 \times 89$
- $358 = 2 \times 179$
- $362 = 2 \times 181$
- $363 = 3 \times 11^2$
- $365 = 5 \times 73$
- $368 = 2^4 \times 23$
- $369 = 3^2 \times 41$
- $371 = 7 \times 53$
- $375 = 3 \times 5^3$
- $376 = 2^3 \times 47$
- $377 = 13 \times 29$
- $381 = 3 \times 127$
- $382 = 2 \times 191$
- $384 = 2^7 \times 3$
- $386 = 2 \times 193$
- $387 = 3^2 \times 43$
- $388 = 2^2 \times 97$
- $391 = 17 \times 23$
- $392 = 2^3 \times 7^2$
- $393 = 3 \times 131$
- $394 = 2 \times 197$
- $395 = 5 \times 79$
- $398 = 2 \times 199$
- $400 = 2^4 \times 5^2$
- $403 = 13 \times 31$
- $404 = 2^2 \times 101$
- $405 = 3^4 \times 5$
- $407 = 11 \times 37$
- $411 = 3 \times 137$
- $412 = 2^2 \times 103$
- $413 = 7 \times 59$
- $415 = 5 \times 83$
- $416 = 2^5 \times 13$
- $417 = 3 \times 139$
- $422 = 2 \times 211$
- $423 = 3^2 \times 47$
- $424 = 2^3 \times 53$
- $425 = 5^2 \times 17$
- $427 = 7 \times 61$
- $428 = 2^2 \times 107$
- $432 = 2^4 \times 3^3$
- $436 = 2^2 \times 109$
- $437 = 19 \times 23$
- $441 = 3^2 \times 7^2$
- $445 = 5 \times 89$
- $446 = 2 \times 223$
- $447 = 3 \times 149$
- $448 = 2^6 \times 7$
- $451 = 11 \times 41$
- $452 = 2^2 \times 113$
- $453 = 3 \times 151$
- $454 = 2 \times 227$
- $458 = 2 \times 229$
- $459 = 3^3 \times 17$
- $464 = 2^4 \times 29$
- $466 = 2 \times 233$
- $469 = 7 \times 67$
- $471 = 3 \times 157$
- $472 = 2^3 \times 59$
- $473 = 11 \times 43$
- $475 = 5^2 \times 19$
- $477 = 3^2 \times 53$
- $478 = 2 \times 239$
- $481 = 13 \times 37$
- $482 = 2 \times 241$
- $484 = 2^2 \times 11^2$
- $485 = 5 \times 97$
- $486 = 2 \times 3^5$
- $488 = 2^3 \times 61$
- $489 = 3 \times 163$
- $493 = 17 \times 29$
- $496 = 2^4 \times 31$
- $497 = 7 \times 71$
- $500 = 2^2 \times 5^3$
- $501 = 3 \times 167$
- $502 = 2 \times 251$
- $505 = 5 \times 101$
- $507 = 3 \times 13^2$
- $508 = 2^2 \times 127$
- $511 = 7 \times 73$
- $513 = 3^3 \times 19$
- $514 = 2 \times 257$
- $515 = 5 \times 103$
- $517 = 11 \times 47$
- $519 = 3 \times 173$
- $524 = 2^2 \times 131$
- $526 = 2 \times 263$
- $527 = 17 \times 31$
- $531 = 3^2 \times 59$
- $533 = 13 \times 41$
- $535 = 5 \times 107$
- $536 = 2^3 \times 67$
- $537 = 3 \times 179$
- $538 = 2 \times 269$
- $539 = 7^2 \times 11$
- $542 = 2 \times 271$
- $543 = 3 \times 181$
- $544 = 2^5 \times 17$
- $545 = 5 \times 109$
- $548 = 2^2 \times 137$
- $549 = 3^2 \times 61$
- $551 = 19 \times 29$
- $553 = 7 \times 79$
- $554 = 2 \times 277$
- $556 = 2^2 \times 139$
- $559 = 13 \times 43$
- $562 = 2 \times 281$
- $565 = 5 \times 113$
- $566 = 2 \times 283$
- $567 = 3^4 \times 7$
- $568 = 2^3 \times 71$
- $573 = 3 \times 191$
- $575 = 5^2 \times 23$
- $576 = 2^6 \times 3^2$
- $578 = 2 \times 17^2$
- $579 = 3 \times 193$
- $581 = 7 \times 83$
- $583 = 11 \times 53$
- $584 = 2^3 \times 73$
- $586 = 2 \times 293$
- $589 = 19 \times 31$
- $591 = 3 \times 197$
- $592 = 2^4 \times 37$
- $596 = 2^2 \times 149$
- $597 = 3 \times 199$
- $603 = 3^2 \times 67$
- $604 = 2^2 \times 151$
- $605 = 5 \times 11^2$
- $608 = 2^5 \times 19$
- $611 = 13 \times 47$
- $614 = 2 \times 307$
- $621 = 3^3 \times 23$
- $622 = 2 \times 311$
- $623 = 7 \times 89$
- $626 = 2 \times 313$
- $628 = 2^2 \times 157$
- $629 = 17 \times 37$
- $632 = 2^3 \times 79$
- $633 = 3 \times 211$
- $634 = 2 \times 317$
- $635 = 5 \times 127$
- $637 = 7^2 \times 13$
- $639 = 3^2 \times 71$
- $640 = 2^7 \times 5$
- $648 = 2^3 \times 3^4$
- $649 = 11 \times 59$
- $652 = 2^2 \times 163$
- $655 = 5 \times 131$
- $656 = 2^4 \times 41$
- $657 = 3^2 \times 73$
- $662 = 2 \times 331$
- $664 = 2^3 \times 83$
- $667 = 23 \times 29$
- $668 = 2^2 \times 167$
- $669 = 3 \times 223$
- $671 = 11 \times 61$
- $674 = 2 \times 337$
- $675 = 3^3 \times 5^2$
- $676 = 2^2 \times 13^2$
- $679 = 7 \times 97$
- $681 = 3 \times 227$
- $685 = 5 \times 137$
- $686 = 2 \times 7^3$
- $687 = 3 \times 229$
- $688 = 2^4 \times 43$
- $689 = 13 \times 53$
- $692 = 2^2 \times 173$
- $694 = 2 \times 347$
- $695 = 5 \times 139$
- $697 = 17 \times 41$
- $698 = 2 \times 349$
- $699 = 3 \times 233$
- $703 = 19 \times 37$
- $704 = 2^6 \times 11$
- $706 = 2 \times 353$
- $707 = 7 \times 101$
- $711 = 3^2 \times 79$
- $712 = 2^3 \times 89$
- $713 = 23 \times 31$
- $716 = 2^2 \times 179$
- $717 = 3 \times 239$
- $718 = 2 \times 359$
- $721 = 7 \times 103$
- $722 = 2 \times 19^2$
- $723 = 3 \times 241$
- $724 = 2^2 \times 181$
- $725 = 5^2 \times 29$
- $731 = 17 \times 43$
- $734 = 2 \times 367$
- $736 = 2^5 \times 23$
- $737 = 11 \times 67$
- $745 = 5 \times 149$
- $746 = 2 \times 373$
- $747 = 3^2 \times 83$
- $749 = 7 \times 107$
- $752 = 2^4 \times 47$
- $753 = 3 \times 251$
- $755 = 5 \times 151$
- $758 = 2 \times 379$
- $763 = 7 \times 109$
- $764 = 2^2 \times 191$
- $766 = 2 \times 383$
- $767 = 13 \times 59$
- $768 = 2^8 \times 3$
- $771 = 3 \times 257$
- $772 = 2^2 \times 193$
- $775 = 5^2 \times 31$
- $776 = 2^3 \times 97$
- $778 = 2 \times 389$
- $779 = 19 \times 41$
- $781 = 11 \times 71$
- $783 = 3^3 \times 29$
- $784 = 2^4 \times 7^2$
- $785 = 5 \times 157$
- $788 = 2^2 \times 197$
- $789 = 3 \times 263$
- $791 = 7 \times 113$
- $793 = 13 \times 61$
- $794 = 2 \times 397$
- $796 = 2^2 \times 199$
- $799 = 17 \times 47$
- $800 = 2^5 \times 5^2$
- $801 = 3^2 \times 89$
- $802 = 2 \times 401$
- $803 = 11 \times 73$
- $807 = 3 \times 269$
- $808 = 2^3 \times 101$
- $813 = 3 \times 271$
- $815 = 5 \times 163$
- $817 = 19 \times 43$
- $818 = 2 \times 409$
- $824 = 2^3 \times 103$
- $831 = 3 \times 277$
- $832 = 2^6 \times 13$
- $833 = 7^2 \times 17$
- $835 = 5 \times 167$
- $837 = 3^3 \times 31$
- $838 = 2 \times 419$
- $842 = 2 \times 421$
- $843 = 3 \times 281$
- $844 = 2^2 \times 211$
- $845 = 5 \times 13^2$
- $847 = 7 \times 11^2$
- $848 = 2^4 \times 53$
- $849 = 3 \times 283$
- $851 = 23 \times 37$
- $856 = 2^3 \times 107$
- $862 = 2 \times 431$
- $864 = 2^5 \times 3^3$
- $865 = 5 \times 173$
- $866 = 2 \times 433$
- $867 = 3 \times 17^2$
- $869 = 11 \times 79$
- $871 = 13 \times 67$
- $872 = 2^3 \times 109$
- $873 = 3^2 \times 97$
- $875 = 5^3 \times 7$
- $878 = 2 \times 439$
- $879 = 3 \times 293$
- $886 = 2 \times 443$
- $889 = 7 \times 127$
- $891 = 3^4 \times 11$
- $892 = 2^2 \times 223$
- $893 = 19 \times 47$
- $895 = 5 \times 179$
- $896 = 2^7 \times 7$
- $898 = 2 \times 449$
- $899 = 29 \times 31$
- $901 = 17 \times 53$
- $904 = 2^3 \times 113$
- $905 = 5 \times 181$
- $908 = 2^2 \times 227$
- $909 = 3^2 \times 101$
- $913 = 11 \times 83$
- $914 = 2 \times 457$
- $916 = 2^2 \times 229$
- $917 = 7 \times 131$
- $921 = 3 \times 307$
- $922 = 2 \times 461$
- $923 = 13 \times 71$
- $925 = 5^2 \times 37$
- $926 = 2 \times 463$
- $927 = 3^2 \times 103$
- $928 = 2^5 \times 29$
- $931 = 7^2 \times 19$
- $932 = 2^2 \times 233$
- $933 = 3 \times 311$
- $934 = 2 \times 467$
- $939 = 3 \times 313$
- $943 = 23 \times 41$
- $944 = 2^4 \times 59$
- $949 = 13 \times 73$
- $951 = 3 \times 317$
- $955 = 5 \times 191$
- $956 = 2^2 \times 239$
- $958 = 2 \times 479$
- $959 = 7 \times 137$
- $963 = 3^2 \times 107$
- $964 = 2^2 \times 241$
- $965 = 5 \times 193$
- $968 = 2^3 \times 11^2$
- $972 = 2^2 \times 3^5$
- $973 = 7 \times 139$
- $974 = 2 \times 487$
- $976 = 2^4 \times 61$
- $979 = 11 \times 89$
- $981 = 3^2 \times 109$
- $982 = 2 \times 491$
- $985 = 5 \times 197$
- $989 = 23 \times 43$
- $992 = 2^5 \times 31$
- $993 = 3 \times 331$
- $995 = 5 \times 199$
- $998 = 2 \times 499$
- $999 = 3^3 \times 37$
- $1000 = 2^3 \times 5^3$

Answer (score 0):

The methods given so far require enumerating primes up to $500$, although Ross Millikan's comment on alex.jordan's answer suggests that only primes up to $\sqrt{1000}\approx31.623$ are needed.  It isn't clear to me how alex.jordan's method is supposed to be adapted to avoid using primes greater than $31$, so I thought I'd show a different calculation that does so.  Undoubtedly this can be made more efficient.

The integers $1$, $2$, $\ldots,$ $1000$ include

- $1$ integer with no prime factors (the number $1$),
- $193$ integers with exactly one prime factor (the prime powers),
- $298$ integers with three or more prime factors.

This leaves $1000-1-193-298=508$ integers with exactly two prime factors.

As shown below, the terms in this expression can be computed using only knowledge of primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{1000}$ and the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

To compute the number of primes between $1$ and $1000$, observe that a composite number in this interval is divisible by a prime less than or equal to $\sqrt{1000}$.  Let
$$
A=\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31\}
$$
be the set of such primes.  Then the set of primes between $1$ and $1000$ is the union of the disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, where $B$ is defined to be the set of integers between $2$ and $1000$ that are not divisible by any element of $A$.  Now $\lvert A\rvert=11$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lvert B\rvert=&999-\sum_{p\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p}\right\rfloor+\sum_{p_1<p_2\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2}\right\rfloor-\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor\\
&+\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3p_4}\right\rfloor-\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
All terms in the ellipsis are zero, as are most terms in the third and fourth summations.  The result is that $\lvert B\rvert=157$ and therefore that there are $168$ primes between $1$ and $1000$.  In addition, there are $11+7+4+2+1=25$ prime powers, including the $11$ squares of the elements of $A$ and higher powers of $2$, $3$, $5$, and $7$.  Note that the fourth summation contains relatively few nonzero terms.  The third summation is the most painful to compute, but this can, in fact, be avoided due to a cancelation, as shown below.

To compute the number of positive integers less than or equal to $1000$ with three or more prime factors, start with the sum
$$
\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor.
$$
This sum overcounts the integers with four prime factors.  (Because the smallest integer with five prime factors is $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11=2310$, we don't have to worry about integers with more than four prime factors.)  Each integer with four prime factors is counted $\binom{4}{3}=4$ times in the sum, so the correct count of integers divisible by at least three primes is
$$
\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor-
3\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3p_4}\right\rfloor.
$$
Note that the summations in this expression are over all primes rather than primes less than or equal to $31$.  The second summation, however, contains no nonzero terms involving primes greater than $31$ since the least product involving a prime greater than $31$ is $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot37=1110>1000$.  In the first summation, at most one of the primes, namely $p_3$, may be greater than $31$.  Hence we may rewrite this expression as
$$
\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor+
\sum_{p_1<p_2\le31,\,p_3>31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor-
3\cdot\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3p_4}\right\rfloor,
$$
which allows us to combine terms with similar terms in the expression above for $\lvert B\rvert$.  (The first summation, in fact, cancels one of the summations in $\lvert B\rvert$.)  The most straightforward way to compute the second summation is to write down all primes up to $1000/(2\cdot3)=1000/6$, that is, all primes up to $163$.  But if you want to avoid using primes greater than $31$, you can do by observing that the only pairs $(p_1,p_2)$ that produce nonzero terms in the sum are $(2,3)$, $(2,5)$, $(2,7)$, $(2,11)$, $(2,13)$, $(3,5)$, and $(3,7)$.  Taking $(2,3)$ as an example, since $2\cdot3=6$ and $1000/(6\cdot32)<6$, each prime greater than $31$ contributes at most $5$ to the sum.  Adapting the prime counting method shown above, we find that

- the number of primes $32\le p\le\lfloor1000/(6\cdot5)\rfloor=33$ contributing $5$ to the sum is $0$,
- the number of primes $34\le p\le\lfloor1000/(6\cdot4)\rfloor=41$ contributing $4$ to the sum is $2$,
- the number of primes $42\le p\le\lfloor1000/(6\cdot3)\rfloor=55$ contributing $3$ to the sum is $3$,
- the number of primes $56\le p\le\lfloor1000/(6\cdot2)\rfloor=83$ contributing $2$ to the sum is $7$, and
- the number of primes $84\le p\le\lfloor1000/(6\cdot1)\rfloor=166$ contributing $1$ to the sum is $15$.

As a consequence, the total contribution of the pair $(p_1,p_2)=(2,3)$ to the sum is $5\cdot0+4\cdot2+3\cdot3+2\cdot7+1\cdot15=46$.  A similar analysis of the other pairs shows that the total contribution of the second summation is $88$.  These computations can be done using only primes up to $11$.

Putting all terms together gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
&1000-1-\lvert A\rvert-(\text{# prime powers})-\lvert B\rvert-(\text{# integers divisible by three primes})\\
&\quad=1000-1-11-25-999+\sum_{p\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p}\right\rfloor-\sum_{p_1<p_2\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2}\right\rfloor-\sum_{p_1<p_2\le31,\,p_3>31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor\\
&\qquad+2\cdot\sum_{p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4\le31}\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{p_1p_2p_3p_4}\right\rfloor\\
&\quad=1000-1-11-25-999+1560-974-88+2\cdot23\\
&\quad=508.
\end{aligned}
$$